# Example of isometry between reflexive and non-reflexive Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, reflexive-space

Let $E,F$ be real Banach spaces where $E$ is reflexive. Let $i:E \to F$ be a surjective isometry. If $i$ is linear, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1299668/368425) $F$ is also reflexive.

> Could you give an example where $F$ is not reflexive?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), there is no such example.